# Google maps v3 - Contextual menu available?

Tags: google-maps

Are there any contextual menus available for Google Maps v3?

Comment: Besides the good examples below, I am still looking for a library I could use, giving me encapsulation and convenient features. Please let me know if you find something like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add context menu as it is decribed here [How to add context menu to google maps, using api V3](http://googleapitips.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-add-context-menu-to-google-maps.html):

Comment: The direct link is http://googleapitips.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-add-context-menu-to-google-maps.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full JQuery solution : http://gmap3.net/examples/context-menu.html

Answer (score 1):

Old question but it came up in my googling so I thought I would post the simplest answer. It's a context menu without the use of more 3rd party js libraries. There's also a latlon object in the event that you can get the lat/lon for where the person clicked, to add a maker or whatever.

```
var contextMenu = google.maps.event.addListener(
        map,
        "rightclick",
        function (event) {
            // use JS Dom methods to create the menu
            // use event.pixel.x and event.pixel.y 
            // to position menu at mouse position


            $('.contextmenu').remove(); //remove previous context menus
            contextmenuDir = document.createElement("div");
            contextmenuDir.className = 'contextmenu';
            //now add our options.
            contextmenuDir.innerHTML = '<a id="menu1"><div class="context">menu item 1<\/div><\/a>'
                                    + '<a id="menu2"><div class="context">menu item 2<\/div><\/a>';

            $(map.getDiv()).append(contextmenuDir);

            contextmenuDir.style.visibility = "visible";

              // might need to offset if you have moved the map div like i did (then - the pixel size off)
                $('.contextmenu').css('left', event.pixel.x ); 
                $('.contextmenu').css('top', event.pixel.y); 

                console.log(event); //log some details about the object we get
            });
```

Comment: > "without the use of more 3rd party js libraries" Looks like you are using Jquery in that code.

Comment: ah true, let me re-phase there. It works without extra 3rd party mapping libraries.

Comment: Note: Official google maps api recommends using the 'contextmenu' event rather than the 'rightclick'. I'm still looking for a simple example using the contextmenu event...

Answer (score -3):

None yet. Google working on one now.