# Get coordinates from Google Maps API 3 with rightclick event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this simple maps code, but for some reason on the rightclick event the alert is not triggered. Could someone help spotting the problem and explaining it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
var lat = event.latLng.lat();
var lng = event.latLng.lng();
alert("Lat=" + lat + "; Lng=" + lng);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Are you sure the `rightclick` event is handled properly? Try doing a `console.log` at appropriate places inside and outside your event handler to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create `map` inside the function `initialize`, so you must add the listener also in `initialize`, otherwise `map` will be `undefined` at the moment when you try to add the listener.

```
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
var lat = event.latLng.lat();
var lng = event.latLng.lng();
alert("Lat=" + lat + "; Lng=" + lng);
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
<head>
  <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
      height: 400px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }
    #display {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?">
  </script>    
  <script>
    var map;
    var myLocation = {  // Belgium
      'latitude': 50.5,
      'longitude': 4.5
    };
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      var displayElement = document.getElementById('display');
      // Add a right click event
      // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168394/google-map-v3-context-menu
      var contextMenu = google.maps.event.addListener(
        map,
        "rightclick",
        function( event ) {
          // just as an example, I write the data to the input
          displayElement.value = 
            'mouse: ' + event.pixel.x +','+  event.pixel.y +
            ' ||| coordinates: ' + event.latLng.lat() +','+ event.latLng.lng() ;
        }
      );
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="display">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to define right click function.

```
/*
  1 = Left   mouse button
  2 = Centre mouse button
  3 = Right  mouse button
*/

$([selector]).mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
        /* Right mouse button was clicked! */
    }
});
```

See [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

Comment: he has defined a rightclick-function(`rightclick` is a event implemented by the maps-API). Using jQuery (or anything else) wouldn't help here, because a DOMMouseEvent will not expose the LatLng.